# Canvas element with blurred lines

Tags: javascript, canvas, blurry

I wonder why the edges/lines of my canvas element are blurred (Chrome, IE, FF) and have a so-called "sawtooth-effect" (does this expression exist in english? :-)) as you can see here:
[image]

It is just a quick first try - maybe I did something wrong? 
Here is the code:

```
c2 = document.getElementById('test').getContext('2d');
c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
c2.beginPath();
c2.moveTo(0, 0);
c2.lineTo(100, 0);
c2.lineTo(80, 50);
c2.lineTo(0, 50);
c2.closePath();
c2.fill();

c2.fillStyle = "#000";
c2.beginPath();
c2.moveTo(0, 50);
c2.lineTo(80, 50);
c2.lineTo(60, 100);
c2.lineTo(0, 100);
c2.closePath();
c2.fill();
```

I also added it to this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5gfs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can oversample the canvas (fake double resolution):

Here's an illustration with standard resolution on top and "double" resolution on bottom:

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/M5NHN/

[image]

Html:

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width=300 height=150></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width=600 height=300></canvas>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas1 {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
}
#canvas2 {
    border:1px solid green;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
}
```

JS:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var context1 = canvas.getContext("2d");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var context2 = canvas.getContext("2d");

draw(context1);

context2.scale(2, 2);
draw(context2);

function draw(c2){

c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
c2.beginPath();
c2.moveTo(0, 0);
c2.lineTo(100, 0);
c2.lineTo(80, 50);
c2.lineTo(0, 50);
c2.closePath();
c2.fill();

c2.fillStyle = "#000";
c2.beginPath();
c2.moveTo(0, 50);
c2.lineTo(80, 50);
c2.lineTo(60, 100);
c2.lineTo(0, 100);
c2.closePath();
c2.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A canvas object has two "sizes": one is the size on the screen and the other is the size of the bitmap supporting the canvas.

You can access the first with `offsetWidth` / `offsetHeight` or using css `width` and `height` values (i.e. `element.style.width` and `element.style.height`). The second size instead is specified on the element itself `<canvas width=100 height=200>` or setting `element.width` and `element.height`.

If the bitmap size is smaller than the screen size then the browser will "upscale" the bitmap using bilinear interpolation, thus creating that blurry effect.

The best crisp graphic can be obtained by setting instead the screen size equal to the bitmap size or, only on devices that use bad tricks like retina displays, by setting the bitmap size to twice the screen size (this is necessary because the screen pixel size is faked in those devices).

If instead what you describe as "blurry" is just antialiasing then I'm sorry but there's no portable way to disable antialiasing when drawing on a canvas, short of drawing the pixels yourself with javascript by accessing the pixel data array.

A canvas with a proper bitmap size is rendered in the best possible way, exactly like an svg "vector graphic" would be. The following is a zoomed view of a screenshot of two lines, one drawn on a canvas and the other from an svg and clearly there's no way to say which is which.

[image]

Comment: thx for your explanation - so I just tried to realize it here: [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5gfs/3/). So far it seems to have no effect on the presentation. Did I miss sth?

Comment: The rendering is just perfect on Chrome on my PC. If you see it blurry may be you're using an iPhone or iPad with retina display. If this is the case then to avoid the problem you should make the canvas size twice the screen size because the browser is tricking you by saying that something that in reality takes 200px on screen is taking 100px instead. See edit if instead what you describe as "blurry" is just the antialiasing effect.

Comment: Hm it is really blurry in Chrome/FF/IE on Win7 PC in the same way as before. The other "trick" you mention does work as shown in the answer from @markE below. So I'll have to do it this way or say.. if the edges should really be "perfect" I think I'll have to draw a svg inestead :-/

Comment: @ho.s: a canvas that is properly sized is rendered exactly with the same quality as an svg. May be you're using a scaled display (e.g. `ctrl+` or `ctrl-`)?

Comment: I tried to compare a svg and a canvas diagonal line in this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5gfs/5/) -maybe my eyes are blurry in the meanwhile because of starring at them too much ;-) .. but to me the svg line seems much more "clean"?

Comment: @ho.s: I've added a zoomed screenshot of part of your fiddle, clearly after changing it so that you're comparing the same line coordinates. Note that a line drawn at 45 degree will always look "better" than a more sloped line and that also what is the color used to draw the line makes a difference. Once you start comparing oranges with oranges you'll see that there's no difference whatsoever.

Comment: I just cannot adjust your example, for me the result is [thisone](http://jsfiddle.net/X5gfs/9/) .. so I'll clearly go for svg, but thanks a lot for your efforts.